# Where do you run "gem install bundler" to make your own gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to make my own gem, but I don't know where to run "`gem install bundler`" in my terminal. And when I ran it in my directory where I have all the other rails projects in it, it first said `Permission denied @ rb_sysopen /Users/km/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/.codeclimate.yml`

so I decided to `chmod` this `.codeclimate.yml` file to 755, but it still gave me the same error so I did `chmod 775`, and now it gave me this error:

`Operation not permitted @ chmod_internal - /Users/km/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/.codeclimate.yml`

I have no idea what I'm doing. I am new to unix commands and rails and still have no idea what this file even is or what permission I need to change. Can someone help, please?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Install bundler or do you already have bundler installed and you're trying to build a gem?

Comment: I'm trying to do all of them, but first I want to get this bundler installed without any error. I keep getting `/Users/km/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:308:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0.a) among 218 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)`

Comment: I searched around and it seems that when I ran `gem update --system` it messed up the global and the local gem (I guess? I don't really know for sure) so the website I found said I should do `sudo gem update --system --no-user-install` but it just told me it's already been updated to the latest version so it aborted.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to achieve some sorts of structure I created different workspaces for my projects. So I have a folder for `gems`, `templates`, `projects`.

In your case, I don't think you should be trying to modify the permissions on your workspaces, rather create a work directory where you have permissions to.

Since you mentioned that you had a project you had your other rails projects in, I'd assume you already have `bundler` installed.

To create your gem IMHO, you should:

1. Create a directory for your gems
2. Run `bundle gem name-of-your-gem-here`

If you navigate to this project folder, you should see the boilerplate for your gem has been generated.

Hope I was able to help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment! I actually don't know why but I've just started to see this problem:

Comment: /Users/km/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:308:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0.a) among 218 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/km/.gem/ruby/2.3.0:/Users/morita/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0', execute `gem env` for more information
 from /Users/km/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:320:in `to_spec'
 from /Users/km/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
from /Users/km/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'

Comment: so I did `gem install bundler` and I got this: 
km:gems km$ gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/km/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/.codeclimate.yml

Comment: I just use `rake install` to build and install a gem when I'm working in the gem's repo. Is that the case? Also, you should run the commands for a gem in the root of the gem project.